# Initializing Wirble from .irbrc produces funny prompt >>

Tags: ruby, irb

When I initialize Wirble (0.1.3) directly in IRB with the following lines, it works well; I get colorized output, auto-complete etc.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'wirble'
Wirble.init
Wirble.colorize
```

When I put the same lines into .irbrc, I get a prompt that looks like this:

```
>>
```

Comment: What's wrong with that? It's the same prompt you get when starting IRB with `irb --simple-prompt`.

Comment: @MichaelKohl I want to have the irb(main):001:0> prompt, just as when I start IRB normally, but I figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the answer is in the Wirble documentation. You initialize Wirble as follows:

```
Wirble.init({ :skip_prompt => true })
```